# Locally patch \newcommand and \newenvironment

Tags: macros

I'd like to define an environment which *locally* patches the `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment` families of commands to prefix each new definition with some string, *e.g.*

```latex
\begin{namespace}{hello}
\newcommand{\world}{Hello, World}
\end{namespace}

\world      % undefined
\helloworld % prints "Hello, World"
```

How can I do this? *Can* I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should cover `\(re)newcommand`, `\providecommand`, `\DeclareRobustCommand`, and `\(re)newenvironment`.  It uses two commands, `\BeginNamespace{<namespace>}` and `\EndNamespace` (which cannot be nested), rather than the environment syntax, because commands defined in environments are lost after the environment ends.

This works by redefining the commands that grab the command name, and adds `<namespace>` before them by using `\csname<namespace>\cs_to_str:N #1\endcsname`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \CStostr \cs_to_str:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newif\if@namespace
\newcommand\BeginNamespace[1]{%
  \if@namespace \ERROR@cannot@nest@namespaces \else
  \@namespacetrue
  \let\NS@new@command\new@command
  \let\NS@renew@command\renew@command
  \let\NS@declare@robustcommand\declare@robustcommand
  \let\NS@new@environment\new@environment
  \let\NS@renew@environment\renew@environment
  \def\new@command##1{%
    \expandafter\NS@new@command\csname#1\CStostr##1\endcsname}
  \def\renew@command##1{%
    \expandafter\NS@renew@command\csname#1\CStostr##1\endcsname}
  \def\declare@robustcommand##1{%
    \expandafter\NS@declare@robustcommand\csname#1\CStostr##1\endcsname}
  \def\new@environment##1{\NS@new@environment{#1##1}}
  \def\renew@environment##1{\NS@renew@environment{#1##1}}%
  \fi}
\newcommand\EndNamespace{%
  \if@namespace
  \let\new@command\NS@new@command
  \let\renew@command\NS@renew@command
  \let\new@environment\NS@new@environment
  \let\renew@environment\NS@renew@environment
  \@namespacefalse
  \else \ERROR@extra@EndNamespace \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\world}{WORLD}
\BeginNamespace{hello}
\newcommand{\world}{Hello, World}
\EndNamespace

\begin{document}

\world      % prints "WORLD"

\helloworld % prints "Hello, World"

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\newcommand*`? ;-)

Comment: @egreg `\newcommand*{\egreg}{Also works}\show\helloegreg` gives `\helloegreg=macro:->Also works.` :)  I patched the internal macros after `\@star@or@long` has done its thing

Comment: You're a good boy!

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a macro `\CsNameToCsToken` which might help accomplishing things without patching `\newcommand`/`\newenvironment`. Besides this it might be useful when using definition-commands other than `\newcommand`/`\newenvironment`:

Syntax:

`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`

`⟨stuff not in braces⟩`  can, e.g., be `\newcommand*` or `\DeclareRobustCommand` or `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\global\long\outer\def` or `\meaning` or `\string` or `\global\let` or whatever.

`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` may be empty. `⟨stuff not in braces⟩` being empty means just calling the control-sequence.

You can nest `\CsNameToCsToken`:

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\global\let{foo}={bar}`
yields `\CsNameToCsToken\global\let\foo={bar}`
yields `\global\let\foo=\bar`.

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\Stopromannumeral{\chardef\Stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
  \@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
    \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\Stopromannumeral#1}%
  }%
  \newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
}%
```

You can, e.g.,  define `\newcommand\namespace{hello}`  and do

```
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{\namespace world}{Hello, World}
```

for defining a control-word-token `\helloworld`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\Stopromannumeral{\chardef\Stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
  \@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
    \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\Stopromannumeral#1}%
  }%
  \newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
}%


\begin{document}

\newcommand\namespace{hello}

\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{\namespace world}{Hello, World}


\helloworld

\texttt{\string\helloworld: \meaning\helloworld}

\texttt{\string\world: \meaning\world}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally you can define a stack for nesting namespaces via `\BeginNamespace{⟨name of namespace⟩}` and `\EndNamespace` so that the macro `\namespace` yields the name of the current namespace:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\namespace{}%
\newcommand*\EndNamespace{\gdef\namespace{}}%
\newcommand*\BeginNamespace[1]{%
  \toks@\expandafter{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\namespace\expandafter{\namespace}}%
  \toks@\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\EndNamespace\expandafter{\EndNamespace}}%
  \xdef\EndNamespace{\the\toks@}%
  \gdef\namespace{#1}%
  \ignorespaces
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\show\namespace
\show\EndNamespace

\BeginNamespace{A}

\show\namespace
\show\EndNamespace

\BeginNamespace{B}

\show\namespace
\show\EndNamespace

\BeginNamespace{C}

\show\namespace
\show\EndNamespace

\EndNamespace

\show\namespace
\show\EndNamespace

\EndNamespace

\show\namespace
\show\EndNamespace

\EndNamespace

\show\namespace
\show\EndNamespace

\EndNamespace


\end{document}
```

Saving the example above as `test.tex`  and compiling yields the following messages on the terminal:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
> \namespace=macro:
->.
l.17 \show\namespace
                    
? 
> \EndNamespace=macro:
->\gdef \namespace {}.
l.18 \show\EndNamespace
                       
? 
> \namespace=macro:
->A.
l.22 \show\namespace
                    
? 
> \EndNamespace=macro:
->\gdef \namespace {}\gdef \EndNamespace {\gdef \namespace {}}.
l.23 \show\EndNamespace
                       
? 
> \namespace=macro:
->B.
l.27 \show\namespace
                    
? 
> \EndNamespace=macro:
->\gdef \namespace {A}\gdef \EndNamespace {\gdef \namespace {}\gdef \EndNamespa
ce {\gdef \namespace {}}}.
l.28 \show\EndNamespace
                       
? 
> \namespace=macro:
->C.
l.32 \show\namespace
                    
? 
> \EndNamespace=macro:
->\gdef \namespace {B}\gdef \EndNamespace {\gdef \namespace {A}\gdef \EndNamesp
ace {\gdef \namespace {}\gdef \EndNamespace {\gdef \namespace {}}}}.
l.33 \show\EndNamespace
                       
? 
> \namespace=macro:
->B.
l.37 \show\namespace
                    
? 
> \EndNamespace=macro:
->\gdef \namespace {A}\gdef \EndNamespace {\gdef \namespace {}\gdef \EndNamespa
ce {\gdef \namespace {}}}.
l.38 \show\EndNamespace
                       
? 
> \namespace=macro:
->A.
l.42 \show\namespace
                    
? 
> \EndNamespace=macro:
->\gdef \namespace {}\gdef \EndNamespace {\gdef \namespace {}}.
l.43 \show\EndNamespace
                       
? 
> \namespace=macro:
->.
l.47 \show\namespace
                    
? 
> \EndNamespace=macro:
->\gdef \namespace {}.
l.48 \show\EndNamespace
                       
? 
> \namespace=macro:
->.
l.52 \show\namespace
                    
? 
> \EndNamespace=macro:
->\gdef \namespace {}.
l.53 \show\EndNamespace
                       
? 
(./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Combining the two ideas you can use `\CsNameToCsToken` inside name-spaces to get the expansion of the `\namespace`-macro as currently defined into names of control sequences—this time instead of `\toks@`-assignments `\xdef` is combined with `\unexpanded` and `\romannumeral`-expansion for redefining `\EndNamespace`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\Stopromannumeral{\chardef\Stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\Stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand*\namespace{}%
\newcommand*\EndNamespace{\gdef\namespace{}}%
\newcommand*\BeginNamespace[1]{%
  \xdef\EndNamespace{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\romannumeral
      \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\EndNamespace\expandafter{\EndNamespace}}%
      {\expandafter\Stopromannumeral\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\namespace\expandafter{\namespace}}%
    }%
  }%
  \xdef\namespace{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \ignorespaces
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\BeginNamespace{A}
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{Hello\namespace}{Hello, A!}%
\newenvironment{\namespace Environment}{This is the start of AEnvironment.}{This is the end of AEnvironment.}

\BeginNamespace{B}
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{Hello\namespace}{Hello, B!}%
\newenvironment{\namespace Environment}{This is the start of BEnvironment.}{This is the end of BEnvironment.}

\BeginNamespace{C}
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{Hello\namespace}{Hello, C!}%
\newenvironment{\namespace Environment}{This is the start of CEnvironment.}{This is the end of CEnvironment.}

\texttt{\CsNameToCsToken\string{Hello\namespace}: \CsNameToCsToken\meaning{Hello\namespace}}%
\EndNamespace

\texttt{\CsNameToCsToken\string{Hello\namespace}: \CsNameToCsToken\meaning{Hello\namespace}}%
\EndNamespace

\texttt{\CsNameToCsToken\string{Hello\namespace}: \CsNameToCsToken\meaning{Hello\namespace}}%
\EndNamespace

\hrulefill

\texttt{\string\HelloA: \meaning\HelloA}

\texttt{\string\HelloB: \meaning\HelloB}

\texttt{\string\HelloC: \meaning\HelloC}

\begin{AEnvironment} \end{AEnvironment}

\begin{BEnvironment} \end{BEnvironment}

\begin{CEnvironment} \end{CEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\BeginNamespace`..`\EndNamespace` is independent from group-nesting and environment-nesting. This might be confusing.